# How can I create an AJAX toggle button with two separate actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to create a two state share button that uses AJAX. As it stands, my share button has two individual actions in my post controller. One is share [POST], the other is unshare [DESTROY]. Lastly, I have a counter that I am trying to use AJAX to update when a user shares/unshares. I succeeded at building a similar button, but this one comes with a do block since I have to embed the font-awesome icon inside of the buttons link_to body. The issue I am having, is I cannot figure out how to set this up properly and render the correct results. How do I create a proper toggle button with two different link_to buttons?

I created two supporting actions for both button states. **share.js.erb** and **unshare.js.erb**. I also have a method that checks whether the user shared or didn't share the post.

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :posts, on: :collection do
    member do
      post :share
      delete :unshare
    end
  end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def share
  post = current_user.posts.new(original_post_id: @post.id)
  if post.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
      format.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end
end

def unshare
  unshare_post = current_user.posts.find(original_post_id: @post.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if unshare_post.destroy
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
      format.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end
end
```

**post/_post.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <% if current_user.shared?(post) %>
    <%= link_to unshare_post_path(post), method: :destroy, remote: true, :id => "share_#{post.id}", style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>
  <i class="fas fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color"></i>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to share_post_path(post), method: :post, remote: true, :id => "share_#{post.id}", style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>
  <i class="far fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color"></i>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</li>
<li>
  <small class="text-muted" id="share_count-<%= post.id %>"><%= post.posts_count ? number_to_human(post.posts_count, :format => '%n%u', :precision => 2, :units => {:thousand => 'K', :million => 'M', :billion => 'B'}) : 0 %></small>
</li>
```

**share.js.erb**

```
<% if !current_user.shared?(@post) %>
$("#share_<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= link_to share_post_path(@post), method: :destroy, remote: true, style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>\n" + "<i class=\"far fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color\"></i>\n" + "<% end %>");
$("#share_count-<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= @post.posts_count ? number_to_human(@post.posts_count, :format => '%n%u', :precision => 2, :units => {:thousand => 'K', :million => 'M', :billion => 'B'}) : 0 %>")
<% end %>
```

**unshare.js.erb**

```
<% if current_user.shared?(@post) %>
$("#share_<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= link_to unshare_post_path(@post), method: :destroy, remote: true, style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>\n" + "<i class=\"fas fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color\"></i>\n" + "<% end %>");
$("#share_count-<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= @post.posts_count ? number_to_human(@post.posts_count, :format => '%n%u', :precision => 2, :units => {:thousand => 'K', :million => 'M', :billion => 'B'}) : 0 %>");
<% end %>
```

**Expected Results**: When a user clicks the share button, the post will show the second state (unshare) and increment the counter.

**Actual Results**: The button doesn't switch states and the counter doesn't increment on the page.

Comment: Don't you forget `#`? `$("#share_count-<%= @post.id %>")`

Comment: I made the change, but I need to apply button swap to the _post.html.erb partial. That's how it looks now **<li></li>**. I'm just wondering if I need to do more in that case. Should I change the logic for the **<li>** tag in _post.html.erb??

Comment: OK, I'll write an answer, how to reload partial template dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload partial template dynamically.

Add tag to `your index.html.erb`.

```
<div id="post_partial">
    <%= render partial: "posts/post" %>
</div>
```

Change your `share.js.erb` to following code. (`unshare.js.erb` is same too).

```
$("#post_partial").html("<%= j (render 'posts/post') %>");
```

Comment: I'm already using AJAX for the _post.html.erb partial with **index.js.erb**. I simply needed to configure the button share/unshare button to toggle.

Comment: @ColePhiper If so, how about changing buttons HTML to partial template and reloading it?